installing paramiko and cryptography fails in linux while using virtual environment for python
I am able to install paramiko and cyrptography when outside the virtual environment.
But when I try:
source env/bin/activate 
pip3 install cryptography

I get the following error:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      error: failed to parse manifest at `/tmp/pip-install-7dbgmwwd/cryptography_8e8b691cfc674e4f870c660144c4fb02/src/rust/Cargo.toml`

      Caused by:
        invalid type: map, expected a sequence for key `package.authors`
       maturin failed
        Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Does your crate compile with `cargo build`?
        Caused by: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:
      Error running maturin: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-no6igq8c', '--interpreter', '/home/aljazry/orch-pro-beta-1.5/env/bin/python3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      Running `maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-no6igq8c --interpreter /home/aljazry/orch-pro-beta-1.5/env/bin/python3`
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

